# Windows 10 Sandbox proxy settings auto-synced with host

Tags: windows-10, proxy, windows-sandbox

I'm trying out the new [Windows 10 Sandbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview) feature and I noticed that I can't change any Proxy Settings (in Control Panel - Internet Options) inside the sandbox. Anything I set there is ignored.

However, when I change them on the host, they are immediately reflected in the sandbox.

So there must be some "syncing" of these settings going on between the host and the sandbox.

Is there a way to disable this "feature"? Or is the sandbox actually merely a "view" on the registry of the host?

Comment: Great question, I had fun researching this one and actually learned something about WSB from it. +1

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Windows Sandbox may not be your best option for whatever it is you're trying to do. This isn't because it isn't a great sandbox, but because it is lacking in advanced features. According to [the manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-configure-using-wsb-file) on setting up a Windows Sandbox configuration file, your options for networking are "Disabled" and "Default".

According to the definition for "Default": "This value enables networking by creating a virtual switch on the host and connects the sandbox to it via a virtual NIC."

So effectively, it would be the same as if you plugged the sandbox into a second ethernet port on your computer, then went to the network adapter settings for your first ethernet port and hit "Share this internet connection" with the second ethernet port. It's not necessarily a "view" issue... It's a "networking implementation" and lack of rich features issue.